# doSMP does not want to start some workers

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I use to load the `doSMP` package in R.

However, today, it does not work and I do not understand why...

I have tried `rmSessions(all=TRUE)` several times, but the problem is still there !

Nonetheless, `getDoParWorkers()` shows that I have not registered a parallel backend...

Do you have a solution for me?

**Error message:**

```
> library(doSMP)
Le chargement a nécessité le package : foreach
Le chargement a nécessité le package : iterators
Le chargement a nécessité le package : codetools
foreach: simple, scalable parallel programming from REvolution Computing
Use REvolution R for scalability, fault tolerance and more.
http://www.revolution-computing.com
Le chargement a nécessité le package : revoIPC
> w <- startWorkers(4)
Erreur dans startWorkers(4) : unable to create a task queue: limit exceeded
De plus : Messages d'avis :
1: In startWorkers(4) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP1
2: In startWorkers(4) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP2
3: In startWorkers(4) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP3
4: In startWorkers(4) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP4
5: In startWorkers(4) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP5
6: In startWorkers(4) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP6
7: In startWorkers(4) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP7
8: In startWorkers(4) : there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP8
9: In startWorkers(4) :
possible leak of worker sessions: consider using FORCE=TRUE
> getDoParWorkers()
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to rmSessions() could be constructed as :

```
rmSessions(all.names=TRUE)
```

(and not all=TRUE), which works perfectly fine on my computer. If that really doesn't work :

```
w <- startWorkers(4,FORCE=TRUE)
```

should get them opened. As explained in the error message by the way. In the odd case the problem is persistent, rebooting Windows is often the only solution. This is also documented.

In any case, you should make sure that you always call stopWorkers(w) whatever happens. This will avoid the problem.

Next to that, if you want to check the DoParWorkers, you first have to register them before they're visible :

```
> w <- startWorkers(4)
> getDoParWorkers()
[1] 1
> registerDoSMP(w)
> getDoParWorkers()
[1] 4
```

Please go thoroughly through the documentation again. You really have to comply to it strictly, or you will get funky business going on in your computer. DoSMP can be a vicious bastard if you don't treat it with caution.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doSMP/doSMP.pdf

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doSMP/vignettes/gettingstartedSMP.pdf

PS : If you tried all of this, and updated to the last versions of R and the packages you use, and it still doesn't work, then please give us a reproducible example (yours can't be reproduced with the correct code) and include all version numbers.

---

On a sidenote, I stopped using `doSMP` as it deadlocks my R pretty often. There are other backends to `foreach` that work better, at least for me. I use `snow` in combination with the `doSnow` package for the `registerDoSnow()` function. In fact, you could as well us `snowfall` for most parallel things. It's a frontend for `snow` and works fine for me.

Comment: Great answer.  I never thought of DoSMP as vicious.  :)  It certainly seems to have behaviors that manifest under Windows that I simply don't see under Linux with doMC - wasn't sure if it was doMC or Windows or my usage.

Comment: @Joris Meys. I will follow you advice: updating my version of R. I hope this would solve the problem. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @Joris Meys. I have just uninstalled my last version and reinstalled the new one, and it works fine! :-)